# Use databinding controls to add records to a dataset

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I imagine this is a terribly Noobish question, and I hate to ask, but I've been trying to solve this problem all day,

I need to add rows to a `DataSet` using databound controls in *VB.net*.

I've set up the data bindings themselves, they're bound the the correct controls, and the `BindingSource` uses the correct `DataSet`. The `DataSet` is filled from the `DataAdapter` correctly, and the binding source works, as the navigation controls all work fine.

Here's the noob part: How do I use the controls to add new data to the `DataSet`?

I've been grappling with this all day. I've tried *Google*, this board, other boards, *MSDN*, everything I could think of, and nowhere did I find a simple tutorial on how to do it.  Either I'm as thick as two short planks, or it's not as simple as I assumed it would be.

Could anyone help me with this please? It's driving me mad.

I guess there must be some kind of end-edit involved which would enable me to *insert*, *update* and *delete* records in the `DataSet` (as you would use with `DataGridView`s)

Comment: Have you tried adding a new row to your `dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new data to the DataSet directly, you can add rows to the DataTables that reside in your DataSet.

You should have a button "Add item" or something like that, and in the event handler add the row to the data table. Ensure that the user can edit your edited row with your bound control and add a button "Save" which would do a TableAdapter.Update() on changed DataTable.

If you use a DataGridView, setting the property `AllowUserToAddRows = true` would add an empty, "dirty" row in which user can type data to add new records to the DataTable.

This two should get you started:

[Walkthrough: Saving Data to a Database (Single Table)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f92s97z.aspx)

[Editing Data in Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233701.aspx)